# ImportError: Scrapy for python no longer works, No module named scrapy.cmdline

Tags: python, module, scrapy, importerror

Running Scrapy yields me the error:

```
ImportError: No module named scrapy.cmdline
```

I looked and I do have that module in the correct location. Can this issue be resolved by creating a new Environment Variable?

Comment: Is the folder containing scrapy on your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Is your PYTHONPATH env var persisted at all?

Comment: Also, have you tried echoing the python path from Python? "import sys; print(sys.path)"

Answer (score 0):

I work on a mac os Lion with enthought distribution and I had the same problem.

In the scrapy.py script file, the problem is that `#!/usr/bin/python` does not reference my enthought python so try changing the #! line to: `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

and the usual python is used

Comment: Thank you. I search a lot and you help me. I open the bin file and found it was installed by python3.9! It works well when I modified it to 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Add the correct directory to `PYTHONPATH` in environment variables.